# How to create a dockable modeless dialog for Microsoft Word using Visual Basic 6

Tags: ms-word, vb6

We are creating an Add-in to Microsoft Word. In it we need to create a dockable , modeless floating pane dialog just like the Style dialog in Microsoft Word Office 365. We use VB 6 for this task. Upto now , I have created a modeless, resizable  and moveable dialog. But it is not getting fixed with the task pane (not dockable )in Microsoft Word.

I used **form1.Show vbModeless** to make it modeless and BoderStyle is set to **vbSizableToolWindow** by the Properties of the form.

Please help me to make it success.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe IDTExtensibility2 includes the capability to create *custom taskpanes*. I know VSTO leverages this to create task panes; VBA doesn't (can't) use IDTExtensibility2, so it can't work with custom task panes. But VB6 is able to. A Google search turned up a number of interesting articles.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338197(v=office.12)

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister. I will try it with IDTExtensibility2